# How do I use a while loop with counter for echoing else statement?

Tags: php, echo, oracle-call-interface

I'm not a full time PHP programmer by any means, but wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be?  I am running a fetch to grab some data that I want to display on a page.  The query results usually have multiple rows.

The following below works great, except for the last else statement for showing none.  This part doesn't work.  Basically I want to display my rows of data and if nothing exists, throw out a message saying "none."

I did some reading around and it looks like with a while loop + multiple result sets you can't simply just use the standard else... both with !empty or isset.

Someone mentioned doing a counter?  Would this be the best way to accomplish this.  Open to any suggestions as I will probably be adding more data like this in the future and would like to do it in the correct fashion.

Thanks!

```
while($myvariable = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
if(!empty($myvariable))
    {
    echo "<tr><th>DISPLAY FIELD NAME:</th><td>" . $myvariable['myrowdata'] . </td></tr>";

    }
    else 
    {
    echo "<tr><th>DISPLAY FIELD NAME:</th><td>None</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at oci_fetch_assoc on php manual. This function is typically called in a loop until it returns FALSE, indicating no more rows exist. So you dont need any other if or else inside your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do the check before the loop by fetching the first row and checking if it's not FALSE; then, if it's not, feed it to the loop and fetch the next row at the END of the loop.  This is called "priming the loop" and isn't uncommon.

```
if(!($myvariable = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt))) {
    echo "<tr><th>DISPLAY FIELD NAME:</th><td>None</td></tr>";
} else {
    while($myvariable) {
        echo "<tr><th>DISPLAY FIELD NAME:</th><td>" . $myvariable['myrowdata'] . </td></tr>";
        $myvariable = oci_fetch_assoc($stmt));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this reference would help you about using function oci_fetch_assoc:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-assoc.php#100304

Answer (score 0):

Your while statement will run only if you get something in your "$myvariable", therefore your if statement is redundant and your else is irrelevant in this case. If you want to run something along the lines of what you're thinking, you can do "oci_fetch_all()" and then loop through and do your if/else.